# Start and stop incoming streams in Wowza programmatically from module?

Tags: java, video-streaming, wowza

How do I start and stop an incoming stream programmatically through the Wowza API? It's easy to do via the management API, and I know Wowza can be configured to do it automatically by monitoring the content directory, but I wish to control it from my module. The Javadocs aren't much help, as it's nigh-on impossible to tell the difference between client API calls for modules, and event notification methods that are meant to be invoked by the container and don't actually do anything :(

Any pointers much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `startMediaCasterStream` and `stopMediaCasterStream` method in `IApplicationInstance` that should do.